# Why is the wedge product skew commutative?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Suppose we have a ring $ R $ and some $ R-$module $ N. $ Let $ a \in \bigwedge^{k} N, $ and $ b \in \bigwedge^{l} N. $

Why is it that $ a \wedge b = (-1)^{kl} \; b \wedge a? $

Comment: This is a perfectly clear question about an important fact. I came here searching for explanations myself. I don’t think more context is needed for something so fundamental.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $a = e_1 \wedge e_2 \wedge \ldots \wedge e_k$, and $b = f_1 \wedge f_2 \wedge \ldots \wedge f_l$, then in order to rearrange $a \wedge b$ into $b \wedge a$, I have to move each of the $l$ terms $f_1, \ldots, f_l$ "across" the $k$ terms $e_1, \ldots, e_k$.  Each time I move an $f$ "across" an $e$, I introduce a minus sign.  So in all there are $kl$ minus signs introduced.

By moving "across", I mean using the identity $e_i \wedge f_j$ = $-f_j \wedge e_i$.

Comment: I was thinking the same, but I don't know how to justify the identity $ e_{i} \wedge f_{j} =  - f_{j} \wedge e_{i} $ in the first place.

Comment: @AddledStudent: That's one of the axioms of the wedge product.

Comment: (Or when it's not an axiom then it is an axiom that $v\wedge v=0$, and therefore $$0=(v+w)\wedge(v+w) = (v\wedge v)+(w\wedge w)+(v\wedge w)+(w\wedge v) = (v\wedge w)+(w\wedge v) $$ so $v\wedge w$ and $w\wedge v$ are always additive inverses.)

Comment: @AddledStudent are you also wondering why $v\wedge v = 0$ (or equivalently $v\wedge w = -w\wedge v$) is a useful axiom, i.e. why the wedge algebra is a useful thing?

Comment: It should be mentioned that $a$ and $b$ may not have this form, but can instead be sums of expressions of this form.

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith I know that the exterior algebra is necessary for the formulation of the Koszul complex, which is important in algebraic geometry because they somehow arise from regular sequences which geometrically lead to complete intersections or something(though I don't fully get why).

Comment: @EricWofsey Because the exterior algebra is graded?